# Exist a way in Ubuntu 20.04 to add an entire wallpaper folder to the background previews in the settings?

Tags: settings, desktop-background

I'm a new Ubuntu (Linux) user.

Ubuntu creates each time a copy when I'm setting up a picture as a desktop wallpaper using the file manager. But if I'm using the settings it doesn't. But the problem is that you can just link one file at once to the selection which is when you have many pictures a big problem.

So my question is: exist a way to link all wallpapers at once or something like that?

The previews in the settings
[image: The previews in the settings]

Comment: Do you want multiple wallpapers, and Ubuntu to rotate through those files, every _x_ minutes?

Comment: for 20.04 Focal. The file is `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/focal-wallpapers.xml` https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePiNS.jpg

Comment: Actually editing the file `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/focal-wallpapers.xml` is required to include your favorite wallpapers. How you edit is your choice. Above script makes the entries for you to copy paste.

Comment: Hello. Yeah exactly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I wrote a very simple python script to generate the Xml code.

Comment: [Link] https://workupload.com/file/uFPW8sYjZ8n [Link]